# my method returns a dictionary, i want this dictionary to be updated when parameter to the method changes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a method called `getsomething(url)` which hits a url and gets some details. This method returns a dictionary. Now as the url changes I want this dictionary which is already created to get updated with new items. How can this be done?

I have tried this:

```
url_list = ['http:something.com','anotherthing.com']

def getdetails(url):
    dict = {}
    # some lines of code here...
    return dict
```

it is getting called here:

```
for url in url_list: 
    result = {}
    result = result.update(getdetails(url))
```

I am getting error like `nonetype object is not iterable`

I need the result of both the url in same dict

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression ? Since you are trying to merge dictionaries

Comment: Assigning `{}` to python keyword `dict` is very bad way to write code.

Comment: `getdetails(url)` is returning `None` so this becomes `result = result.update(None)` hence the error. Make sure your list of urls is valid

Comment: this list of urls i have given here is obviously invalid, as its just an example. I dont understand what do you mean by "getdetails(url) is returning None "

Comment: `dict.update()` returns None.  You can just do `result.update(...)`

Answer (score 0):

to update a dictionary u need to know how a dictionary look.

```py
#// empty dictionary
dic = {}

#// some itmes on dictionary
dic2 = {"one":1, "two":3}
print(dic2)

#// so to update one itme first u need to specifi what item (index) need to be updated
dic2.update(two=2)

print("new =", dic2)
```

Terminal:

```
{'one': 1, 'two': 3}
new = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}
```

Also check this. Is not a shame to search on google believe me. I make this all time is normal.
https://www.journaldev.com/23232/python-add-to-dictionary

ALso make a check state to if that "item" == None or not and if is !=None them make the updates "else" try to check the error and to see what is happen there.